# Azure notifications hub push notification failing or delivering invalid or incomplete data

Tags: php, azure, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub

I am using the following php code to send a push notification to Android application using Azure Notification Hub.

```
$hub = new NotificationHub("Endpoint=sb://ServiceName.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=SharedAccessKey", "ServiceNameNotification");

        $message = '{"data":{"message":"This is a sample notification","title":"Sample Notification","action":"Test","action_id":"60"}}';
        $notification = new AzureNotification("gcm", $message);
        $hub->sendNotification($notification, null);
```

But unfortunately most of the times the notification is not getting delivered, although I am getting a `201` as the response. Whenever it does get delivered, the results are unpredictable, sometimes the contents of old notifications end up getting shown.

The following code is used to show the notifications in Android app (Xamarin.Android) :

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Gcm.Client;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using ServiceName.Helpers;

[assembly: Permission(Name = "@PACKAGE_NAME@.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "@PACKAGE_NAME@.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE")]
//GET_ACCOUNTS is needed only for Android versions 4.0.3 and below
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.INTERNET")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK")]
namespace ServiceName.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Permission = Gcm.Client.Constants.PERMISSION_GCM_INTENTS)]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { Gcm.Client.Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_MESSAGE },
        Categories = new string[] { "@PACKAGE_NAME@" })]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { Gcm.Client.Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_REGISTRATION_CALLBACK },
        Categories = new string[] { "@PACKAGE_NAME@" })]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { Gcm.Client.Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_LIBRARY_RETRY },
        Categories = new string[] { "@PACKAGE_NAME@" })]
    public class ServiceNameBroadcastReceiver : GcmBroadcastReceiverBase<PushHandlerService>
    {
        public static string[] senderIDs = new string[] { Constants.SenderID };

        public const string TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver-GCM";
    }
    // The ServiceAttribute must be applied to the class.
    [Service]
    public class PushHandlerService : GcmServiceBase
    {

        public static string RegistrationID { get; private set; }

        public PushHandlerService() : base(ServiceNameBroadcastReceiver.senderIDs) { }
        protected override void OnMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            string message = string.Empty;
            string title = string.Empty;
            string action = string.Empty;
            string action_id = string.Empty;
            if (intent.Extras.ContainsKey("title"))
            {
                title = intent.Extras.Get("title").ToString();
            }
            if (intent.Extras.ContainsKey("message"))
            {
                message = intent.Extras.Get("message").ToString();
            }
            if (intent.Extras.ContainsKey("action"))
            {
                action = intent.Extras.Get("action").ToString();
            }
            if (intent.Extras.ContainsKey("action_id"))
            {
                action_id = intent.Extras.Get("action_id").ToString();
            }

            // Extract the push notification message from the intent.
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
            {
                // Create a notification manager to send the notification.
                var notificationManager =
                    GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

                // Create a new intent to show the notification in the UI. 
                PendingIntent contentIntent =
                    PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0,
                                              new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity)), 0);

                // Create the notification using the builder.
                var builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
                builder.SetAutoCancel(false);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
                {
                    builder.SetContentTitle(title);
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.SetContentTitle("Notification from ServiceName");
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
                {
                    builder.SetContentText(message);
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.SetContentText("Hello ServiceName User");
                }
                builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_icon);
                builder.SetContentIntent(contentIntent);
                var notification = builder.Build();

                // Display the notification in the Notifications Area.
                notificationManager.Notify(1, notification);

            }
        }
        protected override void OnError(Context context, string errorId)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
                string.Format("Error occurred in the notification: {0}.", errorId));
        }
        protected override async void OnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The device has been registered with GCM.", "Success!");

            // Get the MobileServiceClient from the current activity instance.
            MobileServiceClient client = MainActivity.CurrentActivity.CurrentClient;
            var push = client.GetPush();

            // Define a message body for GCM.
            const string templateBodyGCM = "{\"data\":{\"message\":\"$(messageParam)\", \"title\": \"$(titleParam)\", \"action\":\"$(actionParam)\",\"action_id\":\"$(action_idParam)\"}}";

            // Define the template registration as JSON.
            JObject templates = new JObject();
            templates["genericMessage"] = new JObject
            {
                {"body", templateBodyGCM }
            };

            try
            {
                // Make sure we run the registration on the same thread as the activity, 
                // to avoid threading errors.
                MainActivity.CurrentActivity.RunOnUiThread(
                    // Register the template with Notification Hubs.
                    async () => {

                        try
                        {
                        await push.RegisterAsync(registrationId, templates);

                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
                    string.Format("Push Installation Id " + push.InstallationId.ToString()));


                var res = await MiscServices.RegisterDevice(Settings.UserID, Settings.AccessToken, push.InstallationId.ToString(), "gcm");
                if ((bool)res.data)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Registered InstallationId in Server");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cannot register with Server" + " " + res.status.StatusCode);
                }

            }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        }

                });


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
                    string.Format("Error with Azure push registration: {0}", ex.Message));
            }
        }

        protected override void OnUnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unregistered with Azure push registration");
            }
    }

}
```

Even test notifications fail to get delivered at times, but mostly test notifications work fine. We can't really figure out where the issue is occurring, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you successfully sent messages to Azure NH, and got 201 responses. When you send a notification via Notification Hubs, initially it just gets queued up for NH to do processing to figure out all its targets and then eventually NH sends it to the PNS.

This means that when you are using REST API or any of the client SDK, the successful return of your send call only means that the message has been successfully queued up with Notification Hub.

It doesn’t give an insight into what happened when NH eventually got to send the message to PNS. If your notification is not arriving at the client device, there is a possibility that when NH tried to deliver the message to PNS, there was an error e.g. the payload size exceeded the maximum allowed by the PNS or the credentials configured in NH are invalid etc.

To get an insight into the PNS errors, we have introduced a property called EnableTestSend feature. This property is automatically enabled when you send test messages from the portal or Visual Studio client and therefore allows you to see detailed debugging information.

Or you can try to call via RESTful APIs for troubleshooting:
`https://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/mynotificationhub/messages?api-version=2013-10&test`

Please refer to [Azure Notification Hubs - Diagnosis guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer) for more info.

Comment: I tried EnableTestSend and got successful delivery message to PNS, still a couple of the development devices didn't receive the notification. If this is indeed a problem from PNS side of things, is there a method I can use to check the status in GCM ?

Comment: As GCM is out of our control, maybe you can refer to https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en for more details about how to troubleshooting in Firebase.